# How can I do download of source code of an HTML

Tags: r, xml, rvest, xml2

I'd like to download the source code of an HTML. How can I do it?

I try to use `read_html` of the package `xml2`. But I had an error message.

```
test <- read_html('https://www.epicurious.com/search/Tropical%20Glazed%20Ham%20with%20Curried%20Pineapple%20Chutney')
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.
```

From Mozilla, the source code can be seen through the source.

Comment: Sorry, I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_html` seems to time out for me when I use the url you provided, but for a workaround,  save the raw html code on your file system with `download.file` and then `read_html` from the destination:

```
temp <- tempfile()

download.file('https://www.epicurious.com/search/Tropical%20Glazed%20Ham%20with%20Curried%20Pineapple%20Chutney',
              destfile = temp)

res <- readLines(temp)

library(xml2)

parsed <- read_html(temp)
```